# Android create contact problem

Tags: android, insert, android-intent, contacts

Hi
I wan to create a contact, so here is my code:

```
Intent addPersonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);

addPersonIntent.putExtra(Insert.NAME, "asd");
addPersonIntent.setType(Contacts.People.NAME);

addPersonIntent.putExtra(Insert.PHONE_TYPE, Contacts.Phones.TYPE_WORK);
addPersonIntent.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, Uri.decode("123"));
addPersonIntent.putExtra(Insert.PHONE_TYPE, Contacts.Phones.TYPE_MOBILE);
addPersonIntent.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, Uri.decode("123"));
addPersonIntent.setType(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

...

startActivity(addPersonIntent);
```

Why the only thing that is created is the mobile number, I never got the "work" number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of "putExtra" as adding to the end of an array - Your problem will be clearer if you think of it as setting name/value pairs in a hashtable.  Basically, you're setting PHONE_TYPE to "work", PHONE to 123, PHONE_TYPE to "mobile" (overwriting when it was set to work), and PHONE to "123" again.

What you want to do is set either the "mobile" or "work" phone data using SECONDARY_PHONE and SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE - [Details here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Intents.Insert.html)

Also, keep in mind that all this follows the old version of the Contacts API, which is deprecated as of Android 2.0+.  There's a handy resource on migrating your code to use the new contacts API [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html).

Answer (score 1):

here is the next problem, when I add:

addPersonIntent.putExtra(Insert.NOTES, "asdkjhaskh");

the note data never appears in the activity, why?

The whole idea is to start the EditContactActivity.java with loaded data and for now I loaded phones, names and companies. For some reason I cant load notes, and another problem is how to set in the intent information for the IM? For example I tryed with:

addPersonIntent.putExtra(Insert.IM_HANDLE, "mySkype");
addPersonIntent.putExtra(Insert.IM_PROTOCOL, Uri.decode("skype"));

but it is not working.